# Macros without office installed

Tags: .net, vb.net, ms-word, ms-office

I have a Microsoft word template document (dot) with Macros in it. I need to insert some text, create a new word document and execute one of the Macros. I have tried many options like Aspose, NPOI, NetOffice, OpenXML. All of these create the new document (doc) preserving the Macros in them, but unable to apply/execute the Macro. Can anyone help me figure out how to execute a macro without office installed on the servers?
All of this is done in a VB.Net windows service application using .Net 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to run a macro without Office installed. You may consider moving your code from VBA macro to your application.

Comment: I did consider that and also considered rewriting the macros in OpenOffice Basic, but there are time constraints and too many macros to be tested for it to be a feasible option. Only wish there was a light weight version of office, that did not involve installing office and allowed using the office PIAs. Thank you for your response.